# Supporting Different Screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

im working on Supporting different Screen for android
i created different drawable folders and pasted pics according to their requirments like as bellow

```
drawable-ldpi = 240*320 px (dimension)
drawable-mdpi = 320*480px
drawable-hdpi = 480 * 800px
drawable-xhdpi=720*1280px
```

and then i copy paste layouts in coresponding layout folders like

```
layout-small
layout-normal 
layout -land
layout-land-small
```

etc etc
now when i open the activity_main(layout) of each folder,it has to select the background photo form corresponding folders of drawable,but it select only one photo from drawable-hdpi in all layouts.
where is problem???

Comment: I believe it is a runtime decision by the OS ... could be wrong.

Comment: @Umer Farooq Try in device and check.

Comment: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html

Comment: i'm also thinking that its may be runtime decision and will work properly on device. 
actually i only have one cell phone to test.
is their any good other method to test that either it will select the right picture for the right phone?

Comment: Try clean and build ..it works most of the time..Sometimes the IDE is unable to distinguish between newly created files in the R

Comment: @UmerFarooq try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) to test your app on different device..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android OS automatically selects drawable from specific folder.
You as a developer must only provide different drawable for each folder:

```
drawable-xhdpi/
     awesomeimage.png
drawable-hdpi/
        awesomeimage.png
drawable-mdpi/
        awesomeimage.png
drawable-ldpi/
        awesomeimage.png
```

The best way to show that it works is to launch your application on real device.
You can also use different devices in Android Studio in designer and pictures from different drawable folders should be applied:

[image]

Hope it helped.

Comment: it automatically selects the device for the corresponding layout,forexample if i open the layout-normal-land it will select the device automatically according to the layout.
the Problem is it should select the pic from coressponding deawable folder but it select only one pic for all layouts :(

Comment: Did you try doing it on real devices?

Answer (score 1):

-ldpi, -mdpi, -hdpi, -xhdpi relative to resolution and -small, -normal relative to size, -land relative to oriention of device. You can change to:

```
layout-ldpi, 
layout-mdpi, 
layout-hdpi, 
layout-xhdpi
```

to them select (Order)

```
drawable-ldpi = 240*320 px (dimension)
drawable-mdpi = 320*480px
drawable-hdpi = 480 * 800px
drawable-xhdpi=720*1280px
```

Comment: its still the same showing single pic in all layouts :(

Comment: With this chang you need change resolution of device not size of device. Please check with device with resolution is difference.

Comment: yes im also thinking the same thing that it will work for some different device.
so is it problem of Android studio that its showing same photo in all layouts?
i mean it should also have to show different pics according to different layout...

Comment: I thinks with your problem you need combine size and solution to drawable: example : drawable-small-ldpi, drawable-small-mdpi, ...., drawable-normal-ldpi ....

Answer (score -2):

It selects layout based on the device. It selects only one layout per device. For example, a phone with 4.5 in screen , it selects normal layout, and for tablets it selects large layout.

> These folders are for different devices with different screen sizes and resolution.
>
> As you want all the images to display. You just cant because you device is static in screen size and resolution.
>
> Save all the images in each folders you'll get all the images. This too gets displayed from one folder.
>
> You gotta read developer site to understand better

Comment: Thanks for your answer johna
but when i open them in android studio and in file like (layout-small) or (layour-xlarge) the pic should be selected from drawlable-ldpi for layout-small and drawable-xhdpi for  layour-xlarge but it shows only one pic for all the layouts :(

Comment: Thank you all for helping me :)
i think it will work properly for different devices.Android studio is not synchronizing or helping to do it proper way...